# WinSparkle32.dll not found C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I am using Windows 10 version. For my windows desktop app I am using Winsparkle (https://github.com/vslavik/winsparkle) for autoupdate feature.

As soon as I try to create the object of it, my app get crash.

`public static WinSparkle sparkle = new WinSparkle();`

```
Error : The type initializer for 'MyApp.App' threw an exception. 
Access to the path 'C:\Program Files(x86)\CompanyName\MyApp\WinSparkle32.dll' is denied.
```

When I checked `WinSparkle32.dll` file is not being generated at this path. Only `WinSparkle.Net.dll` is there.

I am using Setup project to generate build. If I run the app as Release in visual studio it works fine and creates both dll `WinSparkle32.dll & WinSparkle.Net.dll` but not working in Release.